# Append items to an array with a macro, in C

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, c-preprocessor

I have an array (**C** language) that should be initialized at compile time.

For example:

```
DECLARE_CMD(f1, arg);
DECLARE_CMD(f2, arg);
```

The DECLARE_CMD is called from multiple files.

I want this to be preprocessed in.

```
my_func_type my_funcs [] = {
   &f1,
   &f2
}
```

It is possible, with a macro, to append items to an static array?

I am using C99 (with GNU extensions) on gcc4.

Comment: What do you mean "called from multiple files"? Are the `DECLARE_CMD` lines in a separate file all on their own? What variant of C (C89, C99, C99 + GNU extensions, etc)? What compiler?

Comment: DECLARE_CMD calls are spread across different source files.
I am using C99 + GNU extensions (gcc 4.4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** in your question there are semicolons at the end of every line. This will seriously interfere with any attempt to use these macros. So it depends on where and how the `DECLARE_CMD(...)` lines are found, and whether you can fix the semicolon problem. If they are simply in a dedicated header file all by themselves, you can do:

```
#define DECLARE_CMD(func, arg) &func,

my_func_type my_funcs [] {
    #include "file_with_declare_cmd.h"
};
```

...which gets turned into:

```
my_func_type my_funcs [] {
    &f1,
    &f2,
};
```

Read [The New C: X Macros](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401387) for a good explanation of this.

If you can't get rid of the semicolons, this will be processed to:

```
my_func_type my_funcs [] {
    &f1,;
    &f2,;
};
```

... which is obviously a syntax error, and so this won't work.

Comment: So i should move all the DECLARE_CMD in headers -- it would be nice if i don't do this, because the directory structure is quite complex. Another problem is that even the my_funcs variable is generated by a macro, so it's trickier to include multiple headers.

Comment: @cojocar — "So i should move all the DECLARE_CMD in headers" ... I would say yes, otherwise I can't think of a structured way to do it. Think about it: there's no way for the preprocessor to hunt around your source tree for occurrences of `DECLARE_CMD`. You need to explicitly tell it where to look.

Comment: You could always `grep` them out of the entire source tree into a temp file that is `#include`d similar to the pattern above to define your table, using a build rule specific to a single target.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can build dynamic arrays **at compile time (not at runtime)** (and thank's to Mitchel Humpherys), the idea is to declare your callbacks in the same section like this:

EXAMPLE:

Suppose you have three files a.c, b.c main.c and i.h

**into i.h**

```
typedef void (*my_func_cb)(void);

typedef struct func_ptr_s {
       my_func_cb cb; /* function callback */
} func_ptr_t;

#define ADD_FUNC(func_cb)                        \
    static func_ptr_t ptr_##func_cb              \
    __attribute((used, section("my_array"))) = { \
        .cb = func_cb,                           \
    }
```

**into a.c**

```
#include "i.h"

static void f1(void) {
   ....
}

ADD_FUNC(f1);
```

**into b.c**

```
#include "i.h"

static void f2(void) {
   ....
}

ADD_FUNC(f2);
```

**into main.c**

```
 #include "i.h"
 
 static void f3(void) {
   ....
 }

 ADD_FUNC(f3);   

 #define section_foreach_entry(section_name, type_t, elem)    \
     for (type_t *elem =                                      \
            ({                                                \
                extern type_t __start_##section_name;         \
                &__start_##section_name;                      \
            });                                               \
            elem !=                                           \
            ({                                                \
                extern type_t __stop_##section_name;          \
                &__stop_##section_name;                       \
            });                                               \
            ++elem)
            

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    section_foreach_entry(my_array, func_ptr_t, entry) {
            entry->cb(); /* this will call f1, f2 and f3 */
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

**IMPORTANT**

sometimes the compiler optimizes start/end sections variables, it wipes them out, so when you try to use them, you will have a linker error: **error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ...**

to fix this problem, i use the following:

1. Try to print your linker script:

   gcc -Wl,-verbose

copy the text between the two:

**==================================================**

in a file (example **lnk.lds**), **you should see thing like:**

/* Script for -z combreloc: combine and sort reloc sections */

OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64","elf64-x86-64")

........

2. ADD your section to the linker script file lnk.lds **after the section .data** like this (my defined section is called my_array as in the example):

> 

```
  __start_my_array = .;
  .my_array :
  {
    *(.my_array)      
  }
  __stop_my_array = .;
```

> 

3. Compile your program with the updated linker script like this:

   gcc -O3 -Xlinker -T"lnk.lds"  file.c -o program
4. If you type **strings program | grep "__start_my_array"** you should find it.

Comment: I get a linker error when using this example:
`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___start_section_name referenced in function ___run`

Comment: try to add __attribute__((used)) to the function that uses __start/__stop section variables, sometimes, these symbols are optimized away.

Comment: Like this?
    void __attribute__((used)) __run() {
        foreach_entry(suites, function_t, entry) {
             entry->function();
        }
    }

Still getting the same issue. I can see my named sections in the .s file however so I'm unsure what the issue might be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
The usual trick is to have all the `DECLARE_CMD(func, args)` lines in one (or more) include files, and to include those in various places with an appropriate definition for the macro.

For example:

In file 'commands.inc':

```
DECLARE_CMD(f1, args)
DECLARE_CMD(f2, args)
```

In some source file:

```
/* function declarations */
#define DECLARE_CMD(func, args) my_func_type func;
#include "commands.inc"
#undef DECLARE_CMD

/* array with poiners */
#define DECLARE_CMD(func, args) &func,
my_func_type* my_funcs[] = {
    #include "commands.inc"
    NULL
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use a single macro to set the function pointers, do the function declaration, set up enums to access the function pointer and strings to use in error messages and later you can use it in a `switch()`.

```
#define X_MACRO(OP) \
  OP(addi, int x, int y) \
  OP(divi, int x, int y) \
  OP(muli, int x, int y) \
  OP(subi, int x, int y)

#define AS_FUNC_PTR(x,...) x,
#define AS_FUNC(x,...) int x(__VA_ARGS__);
#define AS_STRINGS(x,...) #x,
#define AS_ENUMS(x,...) ENUM_##x,

X_MACRO(AS_FUNC)

typedef int (*foo_ptr_t)( int, int );
foo_ptr_t foo[] = { X_MACRO(AS_FUNC_PTR) };

char *foo_strings[] = { X_MACRO(AS_STRINGS) };

enum foo_enums { X_MACRO(AS_ENUMS) };

/** example switch()
#define AS_CASE(x,...) ENUM_x : x(i,j);break;
switch (my_foo_enum){
  X_MACRO(AS_CASE)
  default: do_error();
}
**/
```