# Queuing a call in headers

Tags: c++, module, extern

The goal is to allow header files to "register" an initializer function so that main can just iterate over those functions and call them. I've stumbled upon a solution which uses `__attribute__`, but it seems to be GCC-only (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37082249/7867841).

```
// header1.h
void myInitializer(){}
REGISTER_THIS(&myInitializer);

// header2.h
void myInitializer2(){}
REGISTER_THIS(&myInitializer2);

// main.cpp
...
for_each_registered_ptr(){ call_ptr(); } // calls myInitializer and myInitializer2
...
```

Is there a universal solution to this? Functions can be switched with classes or types if that's easier to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abuse `static` function locals to do this, avoiding the static initialization order fiasco.

In `init.h`, we have this:

```
#ifndef INIT_H
#define INIT_H

#include <vector>

// Can be changed to std::function<...> or whatever you need.
typedef void (*init_fn)();

// Returns int so it can easily be used in a variable initializer.
int register_initializer(init_fn fn);
std::vector<init_fn> & get_initializers();

#endif
```

Then, in `init.cpp`:

```
#include "init.h"

int register_initializer(init_fn fn)
{
    get_initializers().push_back(fn);

    return 0;
}

std::vector<init_fn> & get_initializers()
{
    static std::vector<init_fn> ip;

    return ip;
}
```

A few notes, before we move on to the rest:

- The `static` local is only initialized once, the first time the function is called.
- The "global" vector is kind-of-leaked.  It's unlikely this will be a problem unless you are adding tens of thousands of entries to this vector.  You can always `get_initializers().clear()` to empty it out after using it.

We'd use it like so, in `a.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "init.h"

static void a_init() { std::cout << "a_init()\n"; }

static auto dummy = register_initializer(a_init);
```

And, finally, we have our (rather simple) `main.cpp`:

```
#include "init.h"

int main() {
    for (auto fn : get_initializers()) {
        fn();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting, this solution is thread safe only since C++11 (magic statics)